# Android doesn't recognize my id

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, menuitem

I am developping an app with a menu.
The menu contains 2 items, a map and a settings property
This is the menu syntax:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="+@id/action_maps"
        android:title="@string/action_map"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

I use the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) method in the MainActivity to handle this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreferenceActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.action_maps){
            openPreferredLocationMap();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Now is the problem that Android recognizes action_settings in the method but he doesn't recognize action_maps. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong

```
<item android:id="+@id/action_maps"
    android:title="@string/action_map"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Try this

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_maps"
    android:title="@string/action_map"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

The problem is **+** symbol should be after **@** not before

Answer (score 0):

I removed android:orderInCategory="100" and the Id got recognized again

Answer (score -1):

You accidentally switched "+" and "@" in the action_map item of your menu

Comment: When I started looking into this there was no answer, he just found the answer quicker. But cheers for reminding me why I rarely actually post anything here.